# Regex: Match word between 2 spaces on either side

Tags: regex

This Regex is a bit niche and I'm really struggling to get it down. Here is an example of what I hope it would do:

```
      Testing      space was before this part word space after this part      this part      shouldn't count.
```

I want to try and extract all of the text between either of the two groups of spaces, this is what I've tried so far:

```
 {2}.*?word.*? {2}
```

(Not there is a space before both of the {2}'s)

It should only extract "space was before this part word space after this part". Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Look at  https://regex101.com/r/oOryYx/1, `Testing` is not part of the match.

Comment: If you add spaces before "Testing" it will count those in the Regex though. Sorry I should've clarified that above.

Comment: Then you need `" {2}(?:(?! {2}).)*?word.*? {2}"`, see https://regex101.com/r/oOryYx/2

Comment: That did it, thank you so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
 {2}(?:(?! {2}).)*?word.*? {2}
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/oOryYx/2)

**Details**

- `{2}` - two spaces
- `(?:(?! {2}).)*?` - any char other than line break chars, 0 or more times, but as few as possible, that does not start a two space character string
- `word` - a `word` string
- `.*?` - any 0+ chars other than line break chars, as few as possible
- `{2}` - two spaces